# Load More Produtcs Ajax functionality in magento 2

Tags: magento2, products, ajax

I want to add Ajax functionality for Loading Products on catalog page. https://prnt.sc/TbgsghHe-gVz

I have added the button on the first page . Can anybody help me with the script plz. I want to make custom module for this.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest adding **Infinite scroll** for Load More Products on your listing page.

go to :

> https://github.com/magepow/magento-2-infinite-scroll